# Why wrap the routes around the <Switch> component in react-router when they work just fine without it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Using `react-router-dom` 5.2.0 for what that is worth.

By habit I tend to put all my `Route` components wrapped within a `Switch` component.

Example:

```
const MyRoutes = () => (
  <Switch>
    <Route
      path='/route1'
      exact
      component={() => <Route1Component />}
    />
    <Route
      path={[
        '/route2',
        '/route2/subroute',
        '/route2/subroute2',
      ]}
      exact
      component={() => <Route2Component />}
    />
    <Route
        path='*'
        exact
        component={() => <OtherRoutesComponent />}
      />
  </Switch>
)
```

But I have come to the realization that working without it makes no difference.

So my question is, why use it all? Are there any benefits or disadvantages to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually answered in the [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch):

> How is this different than just using a bunch of `<Route>`s?
>
> `<Switch>` is unique in that it renders a route exclusively. In contrast, every `<Route>` that matches the location renders inclusively.

So in your case, when you go to `/route1`, both `Route1Component` *and* `OtherRouteComponent` would render if you removed the `Switch`.